# ClassNotFoundException in Spark 1.6.0 on anonymous functions from class instantiated from jar file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classloader

I need to load a class from a jar-file at runtime in my spark app (To later sandbox it). To do that, I use an URLClassLoader.

```
val loader = new URLClassLoader(Array(new URL(s"file:///$jarFilePath")), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader)
appClass = loader.loadClass("com..myclass")
val app = appClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[MyClass]
```

It works and I can access methods in my class from the workers but when I try
to set up a spark Dstream pipeline in the loaded class, the jobs fails as the
classloader fails to find the scala anonymous functions.

```
19:31:29.027 [task-result-getter-3] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mycompany.simple.Simple$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
...
```

I think this should be possible as it resembles what REPL does ? Similar SO questions have been solved by adding the jar-file to the classpath (and that works for me as well) but that does not meet my needs as I need to isolate the class in the classloader. Any hints would be appreciated.